# I am trying to reset the state to an empty object after every onClick occurs

Tags: object, reactjs, state, setstate

I am working on a project in React. The idea is that when you search an artist an img render on the pg. Once you click the image a list of collaborating artists is rendered. You can then click a name and see that persons collabpratign artists. Here is my issue: Rather than the state clearing/resetting each time a new artist is clicked, new artists just add on to the original state. Can someone help me figure out how to clear the state so that the state clears and returns a new list of collaborators? Been stuck on this for hours. Here is the code

```
searchForArtist(query) {
    request.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${query}&type=artist`)
      .then((response) => {
        const artist = response.body.artists.items[0];
        const name = artist.name;
        const id = artist.id;
        const img_url = artist.images[0].url;
        this.setState({
          selectedArtist: {
            name,
            id,
            img_url,
          },
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.getArtistAlbums();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  getArtistCollabs() {
    console.log('reached get artist collab function');
    const { artistCounts } = this.state;
    // console.log(artistCounts);
    const artist = Object.keys(artistCounts).map((key) => {
       //kate
      const i = document.createElement("div");
      i.innerHTML = key;
      i.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.searchForArtist(key);
      })
      document.getElementById("collabs").appendChild(i);
    });
    this.setState({});
  }
  //kate
  renderArtists() {
    const artists = this.getArtistCollabs();
  }


  render() {
    const img_url = this.state.selectedArtist.img_url;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type='text' name='searchInput' className="searchInput" placeholder="Artist" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type='submit' className="button" />
        </form>
          <img className="artist-img" src={this.state.selectedArtist.img_url}
          // kate
           onClick={this.renderArtists} alt="" />
          <div id="collabs">
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
const artist = Object.keys(artistCounts).map((key) => {
  //kate
  const i = document.createElement("div");
  i.innerHTML = key;
  i.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.searchForArtist(key);
  })
  document.getElementById("collabs").appendChild(i);
```

What you have done here is manually create html elements and insert them into the dom. As soon as this takes place react has no control over these newly created elements. You should only manipulate the DOM like this when its absolutely necessary. Instead you should be making a new component called something like `<ArtistCollaborators`> and it should take in the artists as props and be what renders the code you have here into the DOM using its own render method.

This will be the React way of doing it, and allows react to be fully control of what you are rendering into the DOM.